# Memory leak , Instrument ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

there is no issue when i check my Application from Product -> Analyze . but when i check it on Instrument it show few leaks object , like.

**Leaked Object**                                                **Responsible Library**

1)Malloc 16 bytes                                                 CorePDF

2)NSMuttableArray                                                 CorePDF

3)CPTextLine                                                       CorePDF

4)CPMemoryOwner                                                    CorePDF
and so on

how can i resolve these leaks ( i am just displaying a pdf file on iPad, when i double tap on pdf it zoom in and that time Object Leaked in Instrument ). if any good link for Instrument tutorial . please give me.

thanks

i am just displaying a pdf file on webView. and the code is

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brochure1" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webview loadRequest:request];
    [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES]; 
}
```

Can any one tell me . That there is any limitations with PDF File which i used in my Resource Folders? because my designer give indexing in PDF File(by software)?

thanks again

Comment: post some code (where you zoom in and out)

Comment: In the address column, you should find a small arrow that you can click and have it show you the retain/release history of an object.  If you can add a sample of that to your post, it would be easier to make a suggestions.  (If you click on a history entry, then select all, you can copy and paste them.)